# How to create album and post image to it,facebook javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to create an app which create an album and post an image from url to it when user click a button and how to set publish_stream permission

The below code is not working

```
FB.api('/PAGE_ID/photos', 'post', {
  url: 'http://example.com/image.png',
  message: 'Upload demo'
}, function(response){
  if (response && response.id)
    console.log('Photo uploaded', response.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is quite unclear. For publish_stream , you may use javascript API as-

```
FB.login(function(response) 
        {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                          // success
           } 
           else 
           {
                         // fail

           }
         },{scope: 'publish_stream,email'}
      );
```